# htmlentities or htmlspecialchars or stripslashes? Which one to use?

Tags: php

When i insert user input data into the mysql database i use, `mysql_real_escape_string`.  The input data contains bbcode e.g. `[img][/img]`.

Below is a line for when the html is output.

```
    $information = $this->bbcode(stripslashes($this->swearfilter($row['information'])),1);
   echo $information;
```

Regarding this example, is this the correct way to prevent a XSS attack or do i use `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES)` or `htmlentities`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS attack

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = preg_replace('#\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]#', '<img src="$1" />', $message);
```

[Prevent XSS Attacks](http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/php-forum/47587-tip-prevent-xss-attacks.html)